# How does update management works for virtual machines in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, auto-update, runbook

We defined the execution's time of the update management with a runbook for 6 hours.

But I would like to know : Does update management work asynchronously (every virtual machines are getting updated at the same time)?.

Answer (score 1):

If they are part of an update domain,

1. All virtual machines within that update domain will reboot together.
2. Update domains are used for patching of the virtual machines.
3. Only one update domain would be updated at the time.